# Ascending Merge Sort to Descending Order

Tags: java, mergesort

As you can see guys currently I am stuck on this merge sort problem and I do not know how to convert this ascending program into descending order in the same format, if someone can help me it would be really kind of you. I am new to this sorting process and I am learning slowly by time, currently I'm a student. Would really appreciate your help guys!

```
private static void mergeSort(int[] array, int low, int high) 
{
    if (high <= low) 
        return;
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    mergeSort(array, low, mid);
    mergeSort(array, mid + 1, high);
    merge(array, low, mid, high);
}

private static void merge(int[] array, int low, int mid, int high) 
{
    int leftArray[] = new int[mid - low + 1];
    int rightArray[] = new int[high - mid];
    for (int i = 0; i < leftArray.length; i++)
        leftArray[i] = array[low + i];
    for (int i = 0; i < rightArray.length; i++)
        rightArray[i] = array[mid + i + 1];
    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = 0;
    for (int i = low; i < high + 1; i++)
    {
        if (leftIndex < leftArray.length && rightIndex < rightArray.length) 
        {
            if (leftArray[leftIndex] < rightArray[rightIndex]) 
            {
                array[i] = leftArray[leftIndex];
                leftIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                array[i] = rightArray[rightIndex];
                rightIndex++;
            }
        }
        else if (leftIndex < leftArray.length) 
        {
            array[i] = leftArray[leftIndex];
            leftIndex++;
        } 
        else if (rightIndex < rightArray.length) 
        {
            array[i] = rightArray[rightIndex];
            rightIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HINT: look for the **one place** (and there _is_ only one) where you're comparing  `leftArray[...]` with `rightArray[...]`, and reverse that test.

Comment: Hello Sir Kevin! Thank you and i have found it out! It was this part! Stay blessed sir!                                                    
 if (leftArray[leftIndex] < rightArray[rightIndex])

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is change the line that compares the items `if (leftArray[leftIndex] < rightArray[rightIndex])` to

```
if (leftArray[leftIndex] >= rightArray[rightIndex])
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing much really changes. Instead of this comparison

```
if (leftArray[leftIndex] < rightArray[rightIndex])
```

you need to do this comparison

```
if (leftArray[leftIndex] > rightArray[rightIndex])
```

Rest of the code stays the same.